# click image and upload to server from android phone

Tags: java, android

I have sucessfully click image and called on next activity where i have given upload button but app is crash when click on upload button. it say --

Could not find class`'com.example.camera.AndroidMultiPartEntity'`, referenced from method `com.example.camera.UploadActivity$UploadFileToServer.uploadFile` and 
These is my upload activity,

```
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private String filePath = null;
private TextView txtPercentage;
private ImageView imgPreview;
private VideoView vidPreview;
private Button btnUpload;
long totalSize = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);

    txtPercentage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    vidPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);

    // Changing action bar background color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(
                    R.color.action_bar))));

    // Receiving the data from previous activity
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // image or video path that is captured in previous activity
    filePath = i.getStringExtra("filePath");

    // boolean flag to identify the media type, image or video
    boolean isImage = i.getBooleanExtra("isImage", true);

    if (filePath != null) {
        // Displaying the image or video on the screen
        previewMedia(isImage);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry, file path is missing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // uploading the file to server
            new UploadFileToServer().execute();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Displaying captured image/video on the screen
 * */
private void previewMedia(boolean isImage) {
    // Checking whether captured media is image or video
    if (isImage) {
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vidPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        vidPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vidPreview.setVideoPath(filePath);
        // start playing
        vidPreview.start();
    }
}

/**
 * Uploading the file to server
 * */
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.FILE_UPLOAD_URL);

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
            entity.addPart("website",
                    new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        showAlert(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

/**
 * Method to show alert dialog
 * */
private void showAlert(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

}

These is my AndroidMultiPartEntity.java

```
public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity

{

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener) {
        super();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode,
            final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary,
            final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode, boundary, charset);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
    }

    public static interface ProgressListener {
        void transferred(long num);
    }

    public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

        private final ProgressListener listener;
        private long transferred;

        public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out,
                final ProgressListener listener) {
            super(out);
            this.listener = listener;
            this.transferred = 0;
        }

        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            this.transferred += len;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }

        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            out.write(b);
            this.transferred++;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }
    }
}
```

config.java

```
public class Config {
    // File upload url (replace the ip with your server address)
    public static final String FILE_UPLOAD_URL = "http://localhost/AndroidFileUpload/fileUpload.php";

    // Directory name to store captured images and videos
    public static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Android File Upload";
}
```

Comment: AndroidMultiPartEntity is in the same package as of your activity ?

Comment: try cleaning your project..

Comment: done with cleaning still the same issue

Comment: Multipart entity is not part of andorid sdk its a lib from Apache. Download here http://james.apache.org/mime4j/

Comment: have added htpmime-4.2.2.jar, httpclient-4.2.1.jar, httpcore.jar

Comment: in project settings Java build Path-> Order and export, check on your libs